# combine series in legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to chart different properties of an object, but have only the name of the object in the legend, so that i can turn off/on the display of the object, not each of the different properties.

in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBz92/) I tried to demo what I would like. So far so good, but in the legend I would like only have 2 entries (2209 and 8444) in this example. This is only an example, there would be more objects and the chart would go unwieldy quickly.

Any help (or pointer to other charting solutions that could do the trick) are welcome. My javascript knowdlege is rather limited..

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back I faced similar problem. This is how I implemented.

- You can not group the legends in highcharts; hence built in option can not be used.
- Instead you need to build custom display for the legends.
- You can list only 2 instead of 8 items (as per your requirement)
- Possible UI elements can be checkbox option (or just hyperlink)
- You need to store the state of the legend (selected/deselected)
- By default display all the charts
- On selection or deselection, you can toggle
  multiple series (4 of 1 kind in your case)

**Sample code here**

```
  // @name is the series name on the chart
  // @newValue would be true or false that is selected or deselected
  ToggleChartSeries = function (name, newValue) {
        // Get matching series or multiple series here
        var matchingSeries = .. // You need to fill the logic here 

        // for multiple series, you can loop through
        if (matchingSeries) {
            if (newValue) {
                matchingSeries.show();
            } else {
                matchingSeries.hide();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks. I played with nvd3 yesterday and managed to get http://jsfiddle.net/taseroth/L9tjX/ but nvd3 appears to be early development and lots of stuff still missing. I will test what you suggested.